# Get free image for commercial distribution from Google API

Tags: php, html, google-api

I would like to get image using Google API in my app. I want to get, based on some keywords, only free image for commercial use.

Is it possible? Do I have to credit Google or the image owner? Can i download the image?

```
foreach ($images as $i) {
    $image = rawurlencode($i);
    $query = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=".$image."&imgsz=large&as_filetype=jpg";

    $json = get_url_contents($query);
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $results = array(); //define array here!
    foreach ($data->responseData->results as $result) {
        $results[] = array("url" => $result->url, "alt" => $result->title);
    }

    echo $results[0]['url'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $query;
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to ask the owners, because they have the rights on the images.

Comment: i want to check if image has "free for commercial use" status